# colorbox-rails gem -- Lightbox is opening entire page, not just photo. How can I fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using the `colorbox-rails` gem to implement a lightbox for a photo gallery. Here's the documentation for the plugin -- http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Here is how I am iterating over the photos in the view:

```
<div id="photos">
  <% @photos.each do |photo| %>
  <%= link_to (image_tag photo.image.url(:medium)), photo, rel: 'photos', data: { colorbox_static: true } %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

When I click on the link of the photo, colorbox opens the *entire webpage* in the lightbox. I would, of course, only like the photo to be in the lightbox.

I've tried stubbing out the path to the photo, but that didn't work.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: no idea regarding this plugin but it would seem your JS is targeting the div with and id of #photos which would cause this behavior. I would look to the JavaScript target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't have complete information, it looks like you are targeting the link on "photo" which appears to be the model.  So you are calling a url that might be something like "photos/1".  Check the page source via your browser to see if you have a line that looks like `<a data-colorbox="true" href="/photos/1">`.

What you want to be targeting is likely "photo.image.url". which would make the target the actual photo rather than the web page where the photo resides.  So perhaps `<%= link_to (image_tag photo.image.url(:medium)), photo.image.url, rel: 'photos', data: { colorbox_static: true } %>` might do the trick?